# I want to make css_selector a repeat statement in python. How can I get that?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

This is python project.

I want to make the code below into repeating using while or for.
Because I have 45lists. I have to get all information from the code.

I think I have to edit the code that 'li.dragons:nth-child(1)' to like 'li.dragons:nth-child(i)'

what should I edit or add the codes to repeat?

I need your help python master.
You can freely edit my code.

```
for i in range(1, 46): since CSS indexes start at , not 0
   browser.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.list_basis  
   li.dragons:nth-child(1) .dragonchild a.link").click() to 
   browser.find_element_by_css_selector(f"ul.list_basis  
   li.dragons:nth-child({i}) .dragonchild a.link").click()

   browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])

   items = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.classname11')

   for item in items:
     name = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.classname12 > 
     .classname13').text
     number = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.classname14').text
     print([name,number])
 
   browser.close()
   browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)! In other words, wrap this whole code block in a for-loop (`for i in range(1, 46):` since CSS indexes start at 1, not 0), then change `browser.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.list_basis  li.dragons:nth-child(1) .dragonchild a.link").click()` to `browser.find_element_by_css_selector(f"ul.list_basis  li.dragons:nth-child({i}) .dragonchild a.link").click()`

Comment: Thank you for answering. I edited my whole code. Is that right? Could you check it please?

Comment: You copy-pasted a bit too much. You just want:

```
for i in range(1, 46):
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
        f"ul.list_basis li.dragons:nth-child({i}) .dragonchild a.link"
    ).click()
```